# How to relax JsHint Bad constructor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, jshint

I am trying to use the transpiled version of async/await in my code which tyepscript website generate when async/await is used.

```
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
        return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
            function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
            function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
            function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(result.value); }).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
            step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
        });
    };
```

However JsHint is complaining about this line:

```
 return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
```

The warning message is:
 `^ Bad constructor.`

Comment: I would run JSHint or similar on the *pre*-transpiled code, not the transpiled result.

Comment: You should run your linter on the *source* code, not the transpilation.

Comment: I am not using typescript, It's just happened that I needed to use the async/await in one of my directives

Comment: This code is not meant to work with it..

Comment: @SMH: So just clean it up to fit your coding standards. I mean, for this specific error, presumably moving the defaulting of `P` to a line above would deal with it: `P = P || Promise; return new P(...` (or if you have JSHint set to warn you about writing to parameters, `var Ctor = P || Promise; return new Ctor(...`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks :)